# Usage of Personal pronoun "I"

Tags: grammar, pronouns, personal-pronouns

Books like word power suggest "Ramu and I are going to theatre today" may be wrong.
Does "Ramu and me are going to ..." a right structure.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what is correct. The version you mentioned as being probably wrong *is* actually the correct one.

Comment: What is it in the book which suggests that?

Comment: This Q is better asked on ell.se

Comment: @WS2 I probably misunderstood the book as it plays different when it is placed as subject and object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mostly depends on what the subject of the sentence is.

"Ramu and I" are the subject, so the use of "I" is required.

Oxford Dictionaries online has a nice guide to help you:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/i-or-me

Comment: OK, when its subject i will use Ramu and I. When it falls as object, then i will use Ramu and me.

Comment: You would say "I am going to the theatre today", not "Me am...", so you would use "Ramu and I are...".

Answer (score 2):

'Ramu and me . . .' and 'Me and Ramu . . .' are found in nonstandard diaelects. It is possible to argue that they are also found in informal Standard English, but, as many might dispute that, it is safest to stick to 'Ramu and I . . .', particularly if English is not your first language.